# Greensock GSAP + SVG Path animations + Scroller

Tags: javascript, svg, scroll, gsap

I'm learning JS animation methods now and I've written this little code that draws and fills SVG paths sequentially by using TimelineLite() and staggerTo() from GSAP library.

```
$('#svg path').each(function() {
          var path = $(this)[0];
          preparepath(path);
});

function preparepath(path) {
    var pathlength = path.getTotalLength();
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathlength + ' ' + pathlength;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathlength;
    path.style.fill = "#fff";
}

var paths = $('#svg path');
var tl = new TimelineLite();
tl.staggerTo(paths, 0.5,  {strokeDashoffset:"0"}, 0.3).staggerTo(paths, 0.5,  {fill:"#000"}, 0.2);
```

Now, the question I'm trying to solve is how to draw an SVG path while scrolling down the window. I was hyped by a wonderful web-site by Bright Media http://brightmedia.pl where I see that they are using CreateJS together with GSAP, but I cannot figure out how exactly the drawing happens.

There is a solution with using the [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/path.html) plugin but I would like to try to use GSAP.

Any pointers on how to draw SVG or Canvas with Scrolling will be highly appreciated! Also, any ideas on how to improve the above as well! I trust in beautiful minds!

Answer (score 0):

You could animate the `stroke-dash-offset` and the `stroke-dasharray` properties.
There is a tutorial on how to do that [here](http://product.voxmedia.com/2013/11/25/5426880/polygon-feature-design-svg-animations-for-fun-and-profit). I also found another one on the same subject [here](http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/).